# Mystery and troubling error from Oracle Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-core, oracle11g

**Scenario:**

- The code in question was tested in our development environment and it works fine (*this is very important, because we only have 1 code base*)
- Oracle 11g
- Oracle Entity Framework 7.21.8

**The problem:**

The Context's **SaveChange()**...saves the data just fine.

But when I tried to retrieve an entity either through EntityEntry's **Reload()** or construct an **IQueryable**, I get this error that is rather vague:

What I have done so far:

- compare the database structure in both environments and they are identical

`Error when executing service method '"FindSoots"'. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.OracleMathTranslator' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. at System.SharedTypeExtensions.GetRequiredRuntimeMethod(Type type, String name, Type[] parameters) at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.OracleMathTranslator..cctor() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.OracleMathTranslator.Translate(SqlExpression instance, MethodInfo method, IReadOnlyList`1 arguments, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalMethodCallTranslatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<Translate>b__0(IMethodCallTranslator t) at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate, Boolean& found)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalMethodCallTranslatorProvider.Translate(IModel model, SqlExpression instance, MethodInfo method, IReadOnlyList`1 arguments, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateInternal(Expression expression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Translate(Expression expression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateExpression(Expression expression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateLambdaExpression(ShapedQueryExpression shapedQueryExpression, LambdaExpression lambdaExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateWhere(ShapedQueryExpression source, LambdaExpression predicate)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.IncludableQueryable`2.GetEnumerator()
at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.UnionWith(IEnumerable`1)
at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1, IEqualityComparer`1 ) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToHashSet[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToHashSet[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at DataProvider.FindSoots(String runId) in DataProvider-Soot.cs:line 99
at FindSoots(FindSootsRequest req, ServerCallContext context) in Service.cs:line 236
at Grpc.Shared.Server.UnaryServerMethodInvoker`3.ResolvedInterceptorInvoker(TRequest, ServerCallContext) at Grpc.Shared.Server.UnaryServerMethodInvoker`3.ResolvedInterceptorInvoker(TRequest, ServerCallContext)
at Grpc.Shared.Server.InterceptorPipelineBuilder`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<UnaryPipeline>b__1>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Grpc.Shared.Server.InterceptorPipelineBuilder`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.CallHandlers.UnaryServerCallHandler`3.HandleCallAsyncCore(HttpContext, HttpContextServerCallContext) at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.CallHandlers.ServerCallHandlerBase`3.g__AwaitHandleCall|8_0(HttpContextServerCallContext, Method`2, Task)

Comment: Couldn't be an issue with server or database settings? Did you compare those?

Comment: Please add the code you use to load/reload this entity that results in this error. The error looks to possibly be related to eager loading navigation properties Does this occur when saving and loading any entity type, or just this particular entity?

Comment: @StevePy...the failure literally occurred at Entity's Reload() call or during the construction of the IQueryable.  I was able to save the data, just not able to retrieve it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by checking the option of "Trim unused code" in the publishing profile.  Sad, but true.